# Value Error in Executing String Formatting {Python, Windows 10}

Tags: python, string

My piece of code:
`print('{:<n1} {:<20} {:<45} {:<20}'.format('No', 'Query', 'Result Path', 'Accuracy'))`

where n1 is an integer variable, something like
`n1=int(query_search[1])`

However, doing so results in a traceback error:
`ValueError:Invalid format specifier`

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will raise a `ValueError: Unknown format code` exception:

```
n = 8

print("{:<n}world".format("hello"))
```

So, one way to achieve the desired behavior, though it's a bit silly, is with an f-string:

```
print(f"{{:<{n}}}world".format("hello"))
```

Output:

```
hello   world
```